# What was that song that played in my hero academia season 3 episode 12?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What was that song that played in my hero academia season 3 episode 12 where all might is kneeling in front of dekus mom?

Answer (score 1):

In case you still haven't found it, it is called Kimi wo Koete. It is from the 2nd Season OST, heres the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aYjvc72T50).